# Value converter shows up in Intellisense but can't be found by compiler in C# WinRT app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, ivalueconverter

I have a value converter located in a shared project that is used by my WinRT app.  That is, the converter is in another project/assembly than the one using it.  I have added the namespace for the other project to my XAML and the IDE does not flag it as unresolved:

```
<UserControl xmlns:CommonConverters="using:Common_WinStore.Converters">
```

I have also added a resource entry for it:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CommonConverters:DebugBindingConverter x:Key="DebugBindingConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

However, the IDE editor flags **CommonConverters:DebugBindingConverter** with the error:

```
The name DebugBindingConverter does not exist in the namespace "using:Common_WinStore.Converters"
```

What is really annoying about this is that when I type *CommonConverters:* the Intellisense pops up *DebugBindingConverter* in the list and I use it to auto-complete the resources reference.

Why can Intellisense find it but not the IDE editor or compiler?

Comment: I face this problem every time I use converters especially in WinRT C# Apps, does it work when you run the application ??

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem earlier. It happens sometimes when you add a new file in project(solution) but do not save the project(solution), intellisense parses it but compiler doesn't compile as it is not included in project file yet. So saving all the files should help. Sometimes issue goes off after restarting visual studio and rebuilding the project/solution.